# SQL Server - Stuck with Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE procedure Sp_GetAllInventoryPivot     
   (@UserID int,          
    @clientID int,          
    @projectID int,          
    @productID int          
)            
as begin            
   declare @pivot varchar(max);            
   declare @sql varchar(max);            

   DECLARE @AttributeNameList nvarchar(max);            
   SET @AttributeNameList = N'';            

   if exists(select AttributeName FROM Attribute where ShowButton=1 and ProductID= @productID)            
   begin            
      SELECT @AttributeNameList += '[' + AttributeName + ']' + N',' 
      FROM Attribute 
      WHERE ShowButton = 1 AND ProductID = @productID AND IsDeleted = 0;            

      SELECT @pivot = LEFT(@AttributeNameList,LEN(@AttributeNameList)-1);            
      print @Pivot            

      SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM           
(SELECT            
 w.WorkFlowTransId as WorkFlowTransID,          
 w.ProjectId,          
 w.ProductID,          
 w.ClientId,    
 isnull((SELECT top 1 DiscrepancyStatusCode            
 FROM [Descrepancy]             
 where WorkFlowTransId=w.WorkFlowTransId order by DiscrepancyStatusCode asc ),'''') as DiscrepancyCode,          
  Attribute.AttributeName,          
   AttributeValue.AttributeValueName,  
   isnull((SELECT count(WorkFlowValueID)            
 FROM WorkFlowValue wfv            
 where wfv.WorkFlowTransId=w.WorkFlowTransId and wfv.WorkFlowValueName=''''),'''') as Status        
FROM Attribute             
JOIN AttributeValue ON Attribute.AttributeID = AttributeValue.AttributeID  
JOIN dbo.WorkFlowTransaction w on w.WorkFlowTransId=AttributeValue.WorkFlowTransId             
 where isnull(w.IsDeleted,0)=0 and isnull(Attribute.IsDeleted,0)=0) as s                   
pivot( MIN(AttributeValueName) for AttributeName in ('+')) as p           
where p.ProductId='+Convert(varchar,@productID)+'           
and p.ClientId='+Convert(varchar,@clientID)+'          
and p.ProjectId='+Convert(varchar,@projectID)+'          
'           
exec(@sql);             
end            
end
```

I want to execute this query in SQL Server itself with hard coded values like `productID = 2` and I don't want the declarations. If I need only the `@sql` in which all values have to be given with no declarations

And I want to see the values in SQL Server itself. How I need to do this? I'm very new to SQL Server. Please help me out by giving your solution .

Comment: If you run the stored procedure, you run everything inside the definition. If you just want to run the query which you build inside it, you can run it as a separate query with hard-coded values instead of parameters. Am I getting your question right now?

Comment: My actual problem is I need the single query to copy and paste in android as I've all the tables using in this stored procedure in android . There I can't give the declarations same in here .

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: still I am not getting your question. what does it mean **"I want to execute this query in Sql Server itself"**, **"I want to see the values in SQL Server itself."**. what does it mean by itself?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your stored procedure is successfully created you can call it like this:

```
EXEC Sp_GetAllInventoryPivot @UserId = 1, @ClientId = 2, @projectID = 2, @productID = 2;
```

`EXEC`keyword is used to execute the command, in this case your stored procedure. You can then specify parameters and their values. Parameter names are optional, so you could also do this:

```
EXEC Sp_GetAllInventoryPivot 1,2,2,2;
```

EDIT: Assuming your question is about running the stored procedure with so-called 'default' values so that it runs even without specifying any parameter, you can initialise the parameters like so:

```
CREATE procedure Sp_GetAllInventoryPivot
@UserID int = 1,          
@clientID int = 2,          
@projectID int = 2,          
@productID int = 2
```

Now you can simply call the procedure without specifying values for parameters.

Comment: I want no declaration . i need a single query with no declaration ., ie., I want only @sql

Comment: What do you mean? There is a variable called `@sql` in your stored procedure. Is that what you want to run?

Answer (score 0):

In new query window , use EXEC command by passing values to stored procedure parameters

eg

```
EXEC Sp_GetAllInventoryPivot 10,2,4,50
```

shows result when you supply values to parameters like below

```
@UserID =10          
@clientID=2         
@projectID=4          
@productID=50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either call the SP directly:

```
exec Sp_GetAllInventoryPivot 1, 1, 2, 1
```

Or, it works even without exec:

```
Sp_GetAllInventoryPivot 1, 1, 2, 1
```

Or, for testing purposes, you may comment out the create procedure part and declare the variables yourself:

```
--CREATE procedure Sp_GetAllInventoryPivot     
--(          
--@UserID int,          
--@clientID int,          
--@projectID int,          
--@productID int          
--)            
--as begin     
DECLARE @UserID int
DECLARE @clientId int
DECLARE @projectID int
DECLARE @productID int

SET @UserID = 1
SET @clientId = 1
SET @projectID = 2
SET @productId = 1
```

If doing this, don't forget to comment out the `END` at the end as well and when switching back to SP creation, uncomment the original lines and comment these eight lines.